# Reflection, generics, eventhandlers and delegates problem

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates, event-handling

I’m struggling with reflection, generics, eventhandlers and delegates. I have a Type which is derived from AsyncCompletedEventArgs. I would like to create a generic EventHandler instance with this Type and also a delegate. Afterwards I want to add this eventhandler to an event.

Can anyone help my creating the eventhandler and delegate by using reflection? All help is appreciated.

```
// The type is derived from AsyncCompletedEventArgs
Type[] typeArgs = { soapServiceInfo.GetEntitiesCompletedEventArgsType };
var eventHandlerType = typeof(EventHandler<>);
var constructed = eventHandlerType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

// getEntitiesCompleted = (sender, arguments) => { }

// soapServiceInfo.GetEntitiesCompletedEventInfo.AddEventHandler(client, getEntitiesCompleted);
```

Comment: What do you want the delegate to do?

Comment: Can you provide the signature of AddEventHandler() ?  Is it (object,AsyncCompletedEventArgs) or is it (object,T) ?

Comment: The signature is (object, T) where T : AsyncCompletedEventArgs.

I have been trying to call CreateDelegate but I was having problems getting the MethodInfo from the lambda function.

GetEntitiesCompletedEventInfo is an EventInfo object.

Answer (score 1):

You can only create a lambda expression for types known at compile time.

You're trying to create a lambda expression at runtime; to do that, you need to compile an expression tree.

Comment: Depending on what the delegate should do, maybe a named generic method would work too.

Comment: What does expression trees have to do with delegates here? -1

Comment: @leppie: He's creating an anonymous method, not pointing to an existing generic method.  He needs to compile an expression tree to do that at runtime.

Comment: @SLaks: I still dont understand why you want to involve expression trees unless the OP want to really do something silly like implement 'logic' at runtime. I dont see any reason why this logic cannot be done at compile-time. From the sample code, I cannot fathom why reflection is even used! :)  (the type seem static and known at compile-time)

Comment: @leppie: `soapServiceInfo.GetEntitiesCompletedEventArgsType` is not known at compile time.  Unless he already has a method that takes `soapServiceInfo.GetEntitiesCompletedEventArgsType`, he needs to generate it at runtime.

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry, my mistake. I'll take my -1 back :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Delegate.CreateDelegate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx)